# String literal is not properly closed by a double-Quote

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm getting an error in the line no 16(starting with '`"<!DOCTYPE`...') on my java file.

```
out.println ( 
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\"

\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n" + 
"<html> \n" + 
"<head> \n" + 
"<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; 
charset=ISO-8859-1\"> \n" + 
"<title> My first jsp </title> \n" + 
"</head> \n" + 
"<body> \n" + 
"<font size=\"12px\" color=\"" + color + "\">" + 
"Hello World" + 
"</font> \n" + 
"</body> \n" + 
"</html>" 
);
```

Error Messge:

> String literal is not properly closed by a doubl-Quote

Dont know whats wrong. Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

String literals are not allowed to span more than one line in Java.

Here you are trying to create a string literal that spans more than one line:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\"
\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n"
```

Instead, split it up in multiple concatenated strings like this:

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\"" +
"\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n"
```

Or place the entire string on one line like this:

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n"
```

The same issue occurs again at the `<meta>` tag.